# JavaScript: Check if moving div has reached a certain point on screen

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a div has moved to a certain point. Here is my code that isn't working.

JS:

```
(function deathCondition() {
    if (wordlist.offsetTop >= 500) {
        alert('hey');
    }
})();
```

I even tried it just being alone.

```
if (wordlist.offsetTop >= 500) {
       alert('hey');
  }
```

Comment: Can you try running `console.log(wordlist.offsetTop);` before the `if` statement, then edit the question with the output? You can view the JavaScript console by pressing F12 in most browsers.

Comment: I did it and it says 52

Comment: You've defined `deathCondition` as an Immediately Invoked Function Expression which means it will only be called once, as soon as it is created on the page, and it cannot be called again. That means it will only ever check `if (wordlist.offsetTop >= 500)` once. I don't know what the rest of your code looks like but this is probably not what you want.

The reason it's not showing the alert with 'hey' is because the condition is not evaluating to true.

Comment: It would help if you posted the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if wordlist contains the id or class of the element, but anyway you need to store the id or class of the element:

```
var wordlist = document.getElementById('wordlist');
```

then find out the elements offset:

```
elOffset = wordlist.offsetTop;
```